# Clone table row and increment input name

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, row, clone

I need to clone a hidden row and increment the name of the input by one. I can currently clone the input but can not clone an element without the name attribute.

How can I clone everything in the cell and also increment the name count?

In my JSFIDDLE example you can see the issue I am running into.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ysfac04k/2/)

```
var c = $(cur_td).find($(children[0]).prop('tagName')).clone().val("")
c.attr("name", $(cur_td).data("name") + newid);
```

On line 38 of the HTML the following button does not clone with the rest.

```
<button type="button"> Info </button>
```

I do not want to give the button a name because I fear it will break my struts 1 action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was that when you were cloning only the first child element of the TD element, just iterate them, like:

from this:

```
var c = $(cur_td).find($(children[0]).prop('tagName')).clone().val("")
c.attr("name", $(cur_td).data("name") + newid);
```

to this:

```
 $.each(children, function(index, childElement){
                 var c = $(childElement).clone();
                c.attr("name", $(cur_td).data("name") + newid);
                c.appendTo($(td));
                });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ysfac04k/4/